# I cant boot into Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi

I recently dual-booted Ubuntu and i can't boot into it.

My first time doing this there were no problems. But now there are and i dont know how to fix it. Here are the errors that appear after trying to boot.

`error: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-45 has invalid signature`

`error: you need to load the kernel first.`

If you need more information let me know because i dont know what information to give in this situation.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you get some sort of a prompt, i.e. can you enter commands, like in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1117403/149708)?

Comment: I was greeted with the error message and after a few seconds it dissapeared. Now im trying to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Did Windows do an update to UEFI and turn UEFI Secure Boot on?

Comment: secure boot was always on

Comment: @Jos tried to do that things in the answer but the errors are the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling Secure Boot solved the problem.

Comment: but that is not best solution although can startup...

Answer (score 2):

**For those people who may not want to disable Secure Boot permanently**

In my case reinstalling `shim-signed` solved the problem.

First, temporarily disable Secure Boot from the BIOS, then reinstall shim-signed:

```
sudo apt purge shim-signed
sudo apt install shim-signed
```

Then re-enable Secure Boot in the BIOS.

Make sure Secure Boot is enabled:

```
sudo mokutil --sb-state
```

Also if you have a third-party driver(e.g. Nvidia) you should reinstall the driver and then, a pop-up window will be displayed asking for a password for enrolling key on the next reboot:

[image]

Then reboot the system and immediately after reboot you will see something like this:

[image]

Select Enroll MOK and then enter the password that you set before.