# Unable to load kernel after fresh install

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I'm trying to boot for the first time after installing Ubuntu, but can't get past the GRUB selection menu.

```
error: Can't read kernel /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.66-generic
error: you need to load the kernel first
```

There are a few questions with a similar problem, but none of the solutions provided seemed to work for me. Things I tried:

- Downloading a new iso and installing Ubuntu all over
- Boot repair using LiveUSB
- Disabling secure boot
- Setting boot parameters as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418401/grub-error-you-need-to-load-kernel-first) fails at

```
linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.66-generic root=/dev/sda2
> Can't read kernel /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0.66-generic
```

Using an Acer Aspire notebook and just replaced my hard drive with a new SSD, if that's relevant.

Comment: you have  sd (solid state) drive ? -  remove it - Try to install with HD , does laptop have two HD slots (bays)

Comment: In stead of installing does liveUSB work with the HD - you done this in past so I think yes

Comment: It has only a single slot. Could the SSD be the issue? I replaced the HDD because it wasn`t working properly.

Comment: Try this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117391/live-usb-error-you-need-to-load-the-kernel-first

Comment: @Keith5001 will check it out, thanks!

Comment: On my solid state system I did efi boot it created a /boot/efi (fat32) on the drive containing all the boot info

Comment: What OS are you using?  That kernel is used by multiple systems, and so more details may help.

Comment: Current installation has Ubuntu 18.04.5. I also went through similar problems with the latest LTS version. Please let me know if you think of any further details that might be useful.