# Load the kernel first

Tags: boot, kernel

I am getting below error, while I am restarting the system.

**failure reading sector from hd0 you need to load the kernel first**

I am using ubuntu 18.04. Please help me to overcome this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you do any updates recently?  How old is the system?

Comment: No @Thomas ward there is no updates recently, I just restarted the system. I bought the system in December 2030

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live USB error "you need to load the kernel first"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117391/live-usb-error-you-need-to-load-the-kernel-first)

Comment: Yes, @Pablo I have tried it, but there is no use. Again getting same problem

Comment: Type `e` at the boot menu in order to edit it for one boot, use trial and error, changing `set root=(hd0,1)` to `set root=(hd1,1)`, `set root=(hd2,1)`,,, `set root=(hd0,2)`, and so on. (sometimes I am lucky the first iteration). If you see a UUID number, this method won't work.